# How to set Arabic values to marker inside map

Tags: android

I m struck on setting marker with Arabic values.I have set Locale.getDefault() for setting default values.I have attach screen shot please go through it. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance. [image][image: english or other language data is showing on marker]

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945530/android-google-map-marker-title-in-arabic-showing-blank) out. it's a little strange way to solve this problem but it work like a charm. if you find a better way let me know.