# Android Google Map marker title in Arabic showing blank

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API v2 for Android, And I have used `Marker` class to add a marker to the map fragment like this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.599114, 39.203938))
            .title("عربي"));
```

but on the map it shows an empty title.

any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it`s a bug, there is no a real solution until now, but you can add an unicode left-to-right mark to the title, something like this:

```
.title("\u200e" +"عربي")
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone reads this post 2017:

Another reason a view is empty might be a restriction to

`singleLine = true`

at some point, e.g. your `getInfoContents()` implementation